# Is it bad form to send a quote from one company to another to get a competing quote?

Tags: ethics, contracts

I have a quote from a company. I would like to get competing quotes.  Is it unethical to send the quotes from the first company, with names and costs redacted, to another one and ask for a competing quote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases it would be bad form.  There is potentially work that goes into the quote beyond just figuring out pricing.  Assuming you aren't going to the first company with catalog numbers in your quote request, they put work into determining you need A, B, and C to meet your needs so providing the quote to a competitor is essentially supplying free labor to the competitor.

Additionally work goes into structuring business documents like quotes (especially if you are talking about detailed quotes for services).  By providing an example of a competitor's document you are giving them an advantage in learning from the competition.

Comment: @anotherdave I can kinda glean an idea of what it means, but it seems to be missing some words and punctuation. Like maybe ", they put" is missing between "quote request" and "work into".

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can send the quote(-ed amounts), but be sure to leave out information that can lead anyone to identify the organization providing the first quote.

However, if you're providing the reference to the amounts, you are essentially allowing them to *match* those numbers (should the second numbers been actually lower). I'd suggest, ask for quote individually and then have the comparison done yourself.

You mentioned

> *It involved a lot of back-and-forth to get them to understand our needs*

well, maybe the requirements need more clarity then. Learn from the interaction with the first vendor, and refine the requirement in a way that successive interactions with other vendors do not need that much back-and-forth communication. There will be a certain amount of discussion needed anyway, that is unavoidable, but a well-formulated and specific requirement can help that keeping at minimal.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely redact the company name and prices.  I will update the question.

Comment: yes, the real problem is you're not clarifying your needs well. The quote stuff shouldn't be multiple back and forth. You can send the same needs to multiple companies to quote on.

Comment: That is not the "real problem".  The majority of the work comes from floor plans and blueprints and how to run the cables in the most efficient way.  I'm sorry I included my reasoning for the question, but it's irrelevant.  The question is, "Is it unethical to send the quote to another company?"

Comment: I have simplified the question.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter if it is "bad form", it's not advantageous to you.

This is purposefully basic.

What if quote A was for $10. Now consider that quote B with no further interference would be $7. You send the amount of Quote A to B. They now quote you $9. Now put millions after that.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Comment: In addition, if the quote was asked in a comparatively general way, OP would deprive themselves from potentially getting quotes that use different approaches to arrive at a solution for their problem.

Comment: You posted this answer after I edited my question to say "costs redacted" so I'm not sure how you arrive at this conclusion.

Comment: What do costs have to do with it? I don't mention, at all, the costs or costs calculations. I assumed you were sending the total amount of the quote to other companies, not how they reached that quote. If that isn't what you are sending, then what, exactly, ARE you sending?

Comment: As a person working in company B to produce the quote, basically I take our costs and add our profit margin and that is our quote. I figure it to be $7. You send me the quote your received from our main competitor and it was for $10. I can stick with my original numbers and send back our quote, or I can increase our profits, unknown to you, and send you a quote for $9. You just cost yourself $2, unknowingly, assuming you take my quote. I get a bonus because I just increased our profits with no extra cost.

Comment: "What if quote A was for $10" "I don't mention, at all, the costs"

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate I understand you do not. I get that really I do. The thing is I don't mention costs either, do I. I say B reads A quote. That's what you say you sent them. You might be thinking win-win. You pay less for B then A and B makes more profit. Except that you are paying more than you would have if you hadn't sent B A's quote, because they had insider's information on their competitors quote, you no longer get a true quote from B, but one modified based on that insider info. If A finds out you would probably get sued.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have a non disclosure appended to it somewhere then it should be ok, but it's not the normal way for many excellent reasons.

Primarily it's essentially useless to ask them to quote based on what another company sent rather than your actual needs/blueprints whatever and usually a site visit as well for cabling with any sort of special needs.

I've done it and would never quote without a site visit even for normal cabling. I'd think it was spam if I was sent someone elses quote. It tells me nothing except materials and time.

Answer (score -1):

I would never base my quote on another’s quote:

1. they may have missed something,
2. they may have a part or similar that they can supply cheap,

So, also considering most quotes that I have asked for have a clause in them along the lines of “ only valid for person xxx and for 1 month from the date above” then you may not have the right to share quotes.